# upsize access 2010 to SQL considerations?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access-2010

I have an Access 2010 database that has grown to 1624MB.  What would be the benefits / items to consider before upsizing to SQL server (free / non-cloud version).  the access database is mostly queries.  I dont have any reports / forms that would be recreated.

due to the current size of the database, queries are progressively taking longer to process.  I will be a newbie at SQL server too.

Answer (score 0):

in database tools, select "compac and repair database" this may make your database size lower without any damage.